# How can i stop the fingers from stretching when i move the body in the Minecraft Rig?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, animation

i have downloaded the Minecraft rig from this website: http://www.rymdnisse.net/download/blender-rigs/minecraft-blender-rig/
,but for some reason, when i move the body around, the fingers streach out. how can i stop this?

Comment: have you checked to make shure that the mesh is properly attached to the bones? it might be that it is not fully weight painted properly so the bones are not moving everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is most likely because you're currently selecting the mesh/skin when trying to move the character.

Instead you need to select those bones in order to move/rotate/scale the character.

This tutorial might help, https://youtu.be/_C3CCz5S75A?t=7m56s (at 7:56)
To move the whole character in while in pose mode, select and move that larger platform around his feet.